# Как убрать пустое пространство справа и слева после установки bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я решил скачать bootstrap и добавить его на свой сайт, после того как я скачал его у меня появилась проблема в html коде а точнее в атрибуте header или header-div.topnav (header div class="topnav"), после добавления bootstrap у меня появились пропуски по бокам, до того как я скачал Bootstrap такого не было. upd. Покопавшись я понял что дело в самом коде bootstrap, изменить я его не решился так как он у меня установлен через ссылку, у меня есть несколько вариантов варианта как это исправить, один из них это - скачать bootstrap и добавить каждый файл туда и изменять код. p.s. при добавлении bootstrap задний фон поменялся с черного на белый, и это тоже проблема (эта проблема связана с самим кодом bootstrap, как писалось ранее)[image: До Bootstrap]

[image: После Bootstrap]

[image: код html]

[image: код css 1/3]

[image: css 2/3]

[image: css 3/3]

Comment: У Вас header встал по контейнеру. Приложите, пожалуйста, вёрстку вашего header

Comment: Я исправил проблему с задним фоном, надо было в html коде поставить код добавления bootstrap выше кода добавления css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я исправил эту проблему не лазая в код bootstrap, я решил поиграться со своим кодом,
зайдя в код Html я поставил код добавления bootstrap выше кода добавления css в теге head, то-есть я поставил - link-rel=css src=bootstrap и ниже код link-rel=css src=index.css. В коде index.css я добавил код body-background-color black (Изменит цвет фона), а также код media (min-width 1000px) .container-max-width 2000px (Изменить размер .container)

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы прежде чем его использовать хотя бы почитали мануалы.
[image: bootstrap .container]

У вас в хедере .container, он ограничивает блоки по ширине. Если вам это не нужно,
используйте .container-fluid. По поводу background у body. Просто пропишите для него свойство.

Comment: У меня проблема с Body-background, у меня в index.css стоит свойство body - background color balck, я посмотрел через код элемента, в самом коде bootstrap-css поставлен код который меняет цвет на белый, сейчас я пытаюсь подсоединить bootstrap на прямую - не через ссылку, и там поменять код. а по поводу container-fluid я не понял, написав в index.css у меня ничего не вышло.